# RSS file with Wordpress XML feed

Tags: xml, wordpress, rss

I need to make a RSS file (for example feed.rss) with XML from my Wordpress feed. Whats important, this fill should be still up-to-date.

Unfortunately I totally don't know how to do this and I don't found anything helpful. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I suggest that you use a plugin? 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/rss-feed

...or is there a reason they wont work?

Comment: Ok, what plugin you suggest?

Comment: It depends completely of your needs but this one is popular and comprehensive enough for most users: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rss-aggregator/